# Juspay SDK Integration Issues

Tags: android

Is juspay SDk present on bintray repository. Because I'm getting this error while building the project. Or is it present on google maven? Can anyone tell me?

Could not HEAD 'http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/in/juspay/hypersdk/2.0.3-rc.77/hypersdk-2.0.3-rc.77.pom'.
Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Comment: Did you not find: https://developer.juspay.in/v2.0/docs/getting-the-sdk

Comment: I did but I could not I understand why I'm getting above error @MorrisonChang

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71044516/edit) your post to include your gradle setup. Also try removing `jcenter()` or placing it at the bottom of any maven repository list.

Comment: juspay SDK is hosted on a different maven.

maven {
          url "https://maven.juspay.in/jp-build-packages/hyper-sdk/"
        }